# How to change the format of time axis of d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data set which has events occurring over the period 00:00 hrs to 23:59 hrs.By default the axis starts with 00:00 and ends with 23:59 but I would like to change the way it is displayed i.e the axis must start from time 08:00 hrs and end with 07:00 hrs.Is there a way to tweak the axis ?

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.time;
        }))
    .nice(d3.time.day, 1)
    .range([0, width - 100]).nice();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));
```

Comment: *"tweak the axis"* is not the adequate solution in a dataviz. Just pass to the domain the interval you want.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: If you want to show the data from 08:00 to 07:00, pass that interval to the domain, and filter out all the events outside it.